# Win32 C++: Using a openfilename and displaying a bitmap file

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, device, openfiledialog

I'm new here, I'm more adapted in C# then in C++.

Therefore, I require the assistance of C++ experts for this dilemnia I am currently having.

What is listed down below is just the code snippet that i think is necessary to complete, nevertheless, i believe there are still more to be achieved.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "winmain.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CommDlg.h>
#include <windows.h>

OPENFILENAME ofn;
TCHAR szFile[260];

switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
                               case ID_FILE_LOADBITMAP:
            bBitmap = !bBitmap;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd,0,TRUE);
            break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
if(bBitmap)
        {
        ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
        ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
        ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
        //
        // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
        // use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
        //
        ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
        ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
        ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
        ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
        ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
        ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
        ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

        // Display the Open dialog box. 

        if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE) 
            hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, GENERIC_READ,
                0, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                (HANDLE) NULL);

    LoadBitmap(__T("F-35C.bmp"), hdc);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
        }
```

As you can see, as i click my case menu: LoadBitmap

It just loads the openfiledialog and choose the file that i want without showing in the Windows, that is all. What i actually want to do is to load the filepath into the LoadBitmap function instead of hardcoding it in the function ("F-35C.bmp).

I also do know that ofn.lpStrFile has the file path, but I am unable to load the Bitmap file despite replacing __T("F-35C.bmp") with ofn.lpStrFile.

As below shows the function of the LoadBitMap Function.

```
bool LoadBitmap(LPCWSTR szFileName, HDC hWinDC)
{
    // Load the bitmap image file
    HBITMAP hBitmap;
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(NULL, szFileName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
        LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    // Verify that the image was loaded
    if (hBitmap == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("LoadImage Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Create a device context that is compatible with the window
    HDC hLocalDC;
    hLocalDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hWinDC);
    // Verify that the device context was created
    if (hLocalDC == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("CreateCompatibleDC Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Get the bitmap's parameters and verify the get
    BITMAP qBitmap;
    int iReturn = GetObject(reinterpret_cast<HGDIOBJ>(hBitmap), sizeof(BITMAP),
        reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(&qBitmap));
    if (!iReturn) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("GetObject Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Select the loaded bitmap into the device context
    HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hLocalDC, hBitmap);
    if (hOldBmp == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("SelectObject Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Blit the dc which holds the bitmap onto the window's dc
    BOOL qRetBlit = ::BitBlt(hWinDC, 0, 0, qBitmap.bmWidth, qBitmap.bmHeight,
        hLocalDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    if (!qRetBlit) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("Blit Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Unitialize and deallocate resources
    ::SelectObject(hLocalDC, hOldBmp);
    ::DeleteDC(hLocalDC);
    ::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    return true;
}
```

To add on, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Developer Version with Win32 Application ( Not Console ).

Comment: So, what is the actual question? I see no question mark in your post. Maybe you should highlight exactly where your problem is specified.

Comment: Just a guess here (your code should be as short as possible and still show the problem) but you have 'hf = CreateFile(...)' after you get the filename from the user. You don't need to and it might cause the bitmap load to fail if the sharing mode is incompatible.

Comment: Thank you all for the comment, appreciated.

The question is : Currently i want to replace the hardcoded "F-35C.bmp" with OpenFileName's lpStrFile.

But it does not work, sorry and thanks once again.

Comment: Yes, i tried using the full path also, but i do need to replace the \ with /, trying to figure out how to do it, currently Googling it, if there is any simpler way for me to get the filename, that will be great!

Comment: You should not need to flip the \, and unless the file is in the current folder, you *will* need the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your `LoadBitmap()` parameters backwards. This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HBITMAP LoadBitmap(
  __in  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  __in  LPCTSTR lpBitmapName
);
```

I'm also fairly certain that you don't need to wrap your filename in `__T()` macro for function calls.

Comment: The LoadBitmap() he calls is his own code, not the Win32 API one.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much, i just realised it too!

Comment: - tinman, the LoadBitmap function was not mine, i took the functions from somewhere else which i forgot where it was, anyway, really grateful to all of you for helping me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in the fact that you are opening the file right after the GetOpenFileName call, the dwShareMode parameter in CreateFile is set to 0 ( no sharing is allowed ) and you do not close or use the obtained handle( hf ). This will result in the failure of the LoadImage call, because the file is still open with no sharing at the time of the call. 
Solution: Either remove the CreateFile call, because it's useless in this code, or close the handle before calling LoadBitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do all of this inside `WM_PAINT`, which will be called many MANY times during the execution of your program.

Load the bitmap once, and keep the `HBITMAP` around.  The painting code should then start with that `HBITMAP`.